# sonar for regular analysis of java maven project

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, sonarqube

I am able to do my project analysis on sonar server using mvn sonar:sonar command in my Ubuntu environment. But now i want to do this on regular basis to see updated version of my project on sonar server. Executing mvn sonar:sonar for my each commit is not a good idea. Is there any way to do this for regular basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for a **Continuous Integration** system. For this you could install ***Jenkins*** and use the [Sonar plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Jenkins+Plugin) to trigger analysis at your preferred rhythm. This is probably the most popular way to trigger sonar analysis.

On the other hand, periodic jobs can be triggered on Ubuntu using [crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

Comment: fine but when reading above [link](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Jenkins+Plugin) i abserved sonar runner...but now i am just using sonarQube. what is sonar runner for. I read about it but unable to get what for runner is used for

Comment: Sonar runner and maven are two alternatives for performing analysis with sonar. See [the documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code)

Comment: This is right, as sonar runner is the most independent way to analyse code, whatever tool was used to build the project. However, if you have ant projects, it might be interesting to look at the [ant sonar documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Ant+Task), especially if you have already defined includes/libraries variables.

Comment: Really you helped me a lot by saving my research time and giving exact solution for my needs thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. However, it seems you have removed one of your comments. In the future please avoid doing this, it makes the discussion more difficult to understand. Other people could find interesting to have the complete reflection you led.